# Why there are two implementation of network io in scalaz-stream?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz-stream

They are located in `scalaz.stream.tcp` and `scalaz.stream.nio`.

- The `tcp` version treats the `Connection` as `Process[Task, A]`
- The `nio` version treats the `Connection` as `Process[Task, Exchange[I, W]]`

Why do these two versions exist? Which situation are they intended for?

Comment: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/pull/250 should answer why there are currently two.

Comment: @FrankS.Thomas Can you make an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are currently two versions because truly the `tcp` version is more like the experimental and future API. The one living in `nio`, has likely more complicated API, but is the one which shall be eventually used for now.